# Maintain Session Across the servers?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have two applications on different servers. One application is on LAMP environment and other one is on ASP.Net 4.0 with IIS7. Main application is in PHP whereas ASP.Net application is just a module of PHP application.

Both of the applications would be sharing same Database which is in MySQL.

I need to share sessions across the servers. Has anyone done this before? I have few thoughts on this -

1. Create Seesion table in MySQL database and let PHP and ASP.Net read/write session into this table. => For this PHP code would need to be changed. Client may not be agreed for this.
2. Since PHP stores sessions in file, write web service on PHP server which would read/write session details to the session files. ASP.Net Application can consume this service to read/write sessions.Service would accept  "PHPSessionId" as an input parameter.
3. Give direct access to ASP.Net application to read/write PHP Session files which are on PHP server. => Not sure giving permission to session files would be a great idea.

Looking forward your advice whether any point mentioned above makes sense or any other best suits as per your experience.

Comment: Out of those 3, option #1 is really the only choice plausible - as long as the DB stores the information you need to share as well.

Comment: But client will not be ready for it as this would require code changes in main PHP application.

Comment: See @AndrewLeap's answer for how to do it with minimal changes to the code. ^^

Comment: _"I need to share sessions"_ - **why**? It's like saying you need to read another program's memory directly. PHP's session files are off-limits other than through the default session handler and API (i.e.: accessing `$_SESSION` from code), you should definitely not read or write those files manually (so #2 and #3 are a no-go). What are you really trying to do? What information do you want to get, and is this information available through other means than session files, be it with a little modification of the PHP application?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend looking into [session-set-save-handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

With a little bit of work, but not anything involving rewriting your php code that uses the sessions, you could push all the session data into the database.  Then it's just a simple matter of writing an interface for that from the C# side.  The most difficult part will be parsing the serialized data, but fairly certain it's something like [Anatomy of a serialize()'ed value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147)

Note that this could be done as a change to a single central php config file, or even by using a `php_value auto_prepend_file`, for instance, `php_value auto_prepend_file dbsessions.php` with the session save handler code in the dbsessions.php file.